# UNION ALLs in dbt <> BigQuery | Querying nested fields

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt

So, we’ve got a few models in one of our dbt projects relying on a `UNION ALL` of two tables in order to provide live reporting, Our models also use a `SELECT *`, which is nice because it means when new fields are added we don’t need to also update these tables (along with the myriad of other things that need to happen), we just do: `SELECT * FROM table_A UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_b`.

Now, using `UNION ALL` is cheap and efficient, so far so good, but it is not nice because it is fragile. As known, unions don’t give a damn about column names and only care about types and column order. So if the order changes between the tables the query breaks. If new columns are added to one and not the other the query breaks. Worse, if the order changes but it happens to still have the same order of types (say, two string columns switch places) it does not break but it is just wrong. We’ve solved some of this issues with a macro that sorts the columns and checks that `table_b` in my example above is always a equal or a subset of columns to `table_a`. A new field would therefore **NOT** break the model, as we just do not select the new field until it is available. However, nested structures are a complete different problem; a new field being added inside a nested field would break the operation, as even though the parent field is present, the schemas no longer match.

Ideally, this mean we would like to descend into nested structures and do something like this:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(nestedField), ARRAY(
        SELECT AS STRUCT
            originalNestedField1,
            originalNestedField2,
            originalNestedField3,
            CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS newNestedField1,
            CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS newNestedField2
        FROM UNNEST(nestedField)
) AS nestedField
```

We’ve tried putting together a macro for solving this, using tools from [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-classes#bigquery-columns). The macro checked if `{%- if col.mode == "REPEATED" -%}` and then relied on something like `{%- for subfield in col.flatten() -%}` to get all subfields. However, the code looked extremely brittle and hacky. Furthermore, our macro would still struggle with unexpected changes in nested fields inside nested fields. As such, in an ideal world, the macro should even be recursive, so it can descend as many nested fields as there are. Has anyone ever experienced something like this? Any recommendations or preexisting open source resources we might find useful?

Comment: Have you tried using the `dbt_utils.union_relations` macro? https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#union_relations-source